# Input is gone after Game asks something on Parchment Parser

Tags: inform7, parchment

Currently working on my first text adventure on Inform7, I ran into a bug when you play the game within a browser using the parchment parser.

The part in which the error occurs is:

```
Calling is an action applying to one topic.

Understand "call [text]" as calling.
Carry out calling:
    if the topic understood matches "Melissa" and the player is carrying the smartphone:
        clear the screen;
        say "You are calling Melissa … she replies 'hey darling. are you fine?'";
        say paragraph break;
        if player consents:
            say "really???";
             say paragraph break;
        otherwise:
            say "oh i see!";
```

The code works fine in any client. But not in a browser. If you call Melissa, the question appears but the input is gone, so no answer could be given.

---

UPDATE:

I just found out, the Version of Parchment was outdated so I manually updated it and now it works.

Comment: Z-Code or Glulx? Can you give us a link to try it ourselves?

Comment: @curiousdannii Z-Code. I just found out, that my version of parchment was outdated, I guess. I updated it manually and now it works. I was about to write a post about it. Thank you. Glulx is another problem, because my game won't work in glulx at all. Just blank screen, so I had to choose Z-Code …